# Migrate from simple MD5 authentication to OpenLDAP

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, md5, openldap

Currently our company uses a very simple login system involving salted MD5 hashes stored in a database and compared with passwords POSTED to a PHP page. We manage page view permission using PHPGACL. Now that our company has shifted from managing a couple dozen logins to a few hundred this system obviously not only presents a security threat but is also a maintenance hassle as we start to integrate more enterprise tools into our system and need users to have distinct logins for each tool.

From my understanding, OpenLDAP will allow us to replace this system with a single login that works across many platforms (google services, JIRA, etc) and a more secure password encryption mechanism. It would also still allow us to maintain the same page access controls that phpGACL offers.

Is this correct or do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what LDAP is supposed to do? Are there any technologies other than OpenLDAP that would be necessary for migrating a system like the one we currently have? I've heard good things about LDAP but I'm still not very clear on what it actually does and does not do.

Answer (score 0):

Many applications are able to use external (meaning external to the application) LDAP repositories for Authentication and some for Authorization. But, Not ALL applications will work with LDAP.

Google services typically requires some federation or synchronization to be used with LDAP.

You would need to verify other applications ability to utilize LDAP.
-jim